# Help creating HTML page with curved header section

Tags: html, css, graphics, css-shapes

I was wondering, what is the best way (using html, css, and graphics) to create a web page whose top header section appears to be beveled, as opposed to straight across?  Please see the below image as an example:

[image]

I'm not sure how to use images in a way such that they would expand/contract in accordance with different browser sizes/resolutions...

Can anyone offer me some help? Or perhaps point me to a resource?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your width fixed? Or is it fluid with perhaps a `min-width` and a `max-width`?

Comment: I haven't created anything yet, but I was hoping to make it a fluid width if possible

Comment: I think you can with `border-radious` and negative values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `border-radius`.

[image: Example]

[See my example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p2hH7/).

Comment: I don't know how cross-compatible this is, CSS3 only I think.

Comment: @JCOC611 Yep, it a CSS3 property, that will work today in Safari, Chrome, Firefox and IE9. Luckily, it degrades gracefully (depending on your requirements however).

Comment: @ahonorstudent No it won't. css3pie can only handle border radius for the entire block, it does not accept border radius for certain corners only.

Answer (score 2):

Mine is a cleaner version of @Alex's:

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/3JRAc/)

```css
.head {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 40% 80px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 40% 80px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 40% 80px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 40% 80px;
    border-top-left-radius: 40% 80px;
    border-top-right-radius: 40% 80px;

    background: blue;
    height: 280px
}
```

```html
<div class="head"></div>
```

It obviously won't work in IE.

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS3 or webkit-specific properties, but this is not well supported as far as cross-browser compatibility is concerned. If you want to support as many browsers as possible, your best bet would be to use a background image to achieve this effect.

Comment: You're right, I do want my solution to be as cross-browser as possible.  I might just go with a background image...

Comment: @behrk2: If you want a solution which works with older browsers *and is fluid*, then your best bet would be to use two background images (the left and right rounded sections respectively). If you'd like more details on how to do this, leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cross-browser version, which i made with help of jquery. Basically, the script creates many spans, with white background and decreasing width.

You can play around with `STEPS` and `FACTOR` variables, which will change the result. The step function sets the easing of the curve. You may replace it later with better functions than mine, it's just an example.

```
var STEPS = 53;
var FACTOR = 5;

var $el = $('div.header');
var width = $el.outerWidth();
var $span = $('<span></span>');
for(i=0;i<STEPS;i++){
    tmpWidth = stepWidth(i, width);
    $span.clone().css({
        'bottom': i + 'px',
        'width': tmpWidth,
        'left': (width - tmpWidth)/2
    }).appendTo($el);

}
function stepWidth(i, width){
    return -(1 / FACTOR * Math.pow(i, 2)) + width;
}
```

[image]

You can find the entire code (html + css on the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/everton/He5k2/4/))

Comment: additionally, you could bind a function on your window resize event to redraw this guys

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of achieving this.

1. Draw an overlay with pseudo element with `width` and `height` larger than element itself.
2. Apply `border-radius` to create round effect and `background-color`.
3. Add `overflow: hidden` on parent to hide excess part.

**Output Image:**

[image: Output Image]

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(lightblue, blue);
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5vh auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 90vh;
  width: 500px;
}

.box:before {
  border-radius: 100% 100% 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  bottom: -200px;
  right: -200px;
  left: -200px;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  
</div>
```