# Adding radius in center of div not corner

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I know html and css very well , i'm looking for something like this with css not with images ?
[image]
is there any trick that can do this with Css ?
**HTML**

```
<div id="zone-user-wrapper" class="zone-wrapper"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.zone-wrapper{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #01b888;
    height:150px;
}
```

i made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hL2nhzyf/)

Thx

Comment: A gray rectangle in background and a white non transparent div with _very_ round corners on top?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777916/help-creating-html-page-with-curved-header-section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hL2nhzyf/4/)

#### HTML:

```
<div class="zone-wrapper"></div>
<div id="shape"></div>
```

#### CSS:

```
.zone-wrapper{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #01b888;
    height:150px;
}
#shape {
    height: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    border-top-left-radius: 5000px 300px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5000px 300px;
    top: -20px;
    position: relative;
}
```

### <------------------------------------------------------------ Edit ------------------------------------------------------------->

Replicating the one on this [website](http://www.ghosthorses.co.uk/) as you requested.

Here, I've added the `border-top-left-radius: 4000px 150px` and `border-top-right-radius: 4000px 150px;` to `.content` and `.seperator`. Then, gave appropriate z-index to all elements. `.content` has the highest `z-index` value, `.zone-wrapper` has the lowest `z-index` value and `.seperator` is in the middle.

### <--------------------[ [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v68Lgo8b/) | [Full Screen Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v68Lgo8b/embedded/result/) | [With the Image](http://jsfiddle.net/v68Lgo8b/2/embedded/result/) from your [website](http://webpen.ir/) ]-------------------->

#### HTML:

```
<div class="zone-wrapper"></div>
<div class="seperator"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

#### CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0 0;
}
.zone-wrapper{
    background: url(http://s25.postimg.org/4lur4kk23/pattern.png) repeat scroll 0 0 #01b888;
    height:180px;
    z-index: 0;
}
.seperator {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #00533D;
    border-top-left-radius: 4000px 150px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4000px 150px;
    top: -47px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.content {
    top: -90px;
    position: relative;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: #93fbdf;
    border-top-left-radius: 4000px 150px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4000px 150px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Yea it's totally fine.

Comment: thx but it's not the best using html and css .
take look at http://www.ghosthorses.co.uk/ .
it's better than css , what do u think ?

Comment: @user3642164 - Check out my edited answer, I'm pretty sure you'll like this one!

Answer (score 1):

### The Flexible Option with a single HTML element

I have focused on creating the shape with a:

1. single HTML element — `<header></header>`
2. flexible percentage units

### The CSS

- The `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements overlap to create the curve
- The pseudo elements are given 100% width and will expand and retract
- The box shadow helps smooth out the jagged curve and the textured background image distracts the eyes from the remaining jagged pixels
- The `left: -20px` and `padding-right: 20px` hide the rounded corner and are cut-off with `overflow: hidden`

**Image Attribution:** The background image used in the example below is obtained from [transparenttextures.com](http://www.transparenttextures.com/) and was created by Atle Mo.

### The Example

Open full-screen and watch it re-size.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIgas.png);
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
header:after,
header:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: #FFF;
  height: 60%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100% 100% 0 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: -20px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px #333;
}
header:before {
  background: #333;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.zone-wrapper{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #01b888;
    height:150px;
  border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.zone-wrapper2{
  margin-top:10px;
  display:inlin-block;
    background: black;
    height:130px;
  border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="zone-user-wrapper" class="zone-wrapper">

<div id="div2" class="zone-wrapper2">


</div>
</div>
```

Comment: here is my site : webpen.ir
i want to add a little radius in center below my menu . this code does'nt do this

Comment: well, i think you can find the solution in this interesting post :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698830/curved-lines-using-only-html-and-or-css

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this from (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4777943/3905567):

`<div id="header">
    <div id="cover-left"></div>
    <div id="cover-right"></div>
</div>`

http://jsfiddle.net/p2hH7/215/

Comment: thx , but you know what !! it's not the best option with css ,is'n it ?
check my site plz : webpen.ir , i want to add a radius below my menu

Comment: I had mentioned in the earlier comment. Have included the link now.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to have 2 divs. The first could be your actual header and another just beneath it having a border-radius property. So your whole header could be a wrapper around the 2.

Did some tinkering to the html of your code.
Added a div in the main header wrapper.

Check the image below:

[image]
Hope it is of help.

Comment: @user3642164 Even if not full way to the source img u presented - I hope it goes some way in solving the dilemma

Comment: thx man , this helped me a lot , but this is not what i'm looking for